# Windows won't PASTE unless it's immediately after a COPY

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 64-bit.

When I copy something using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, Right-Click Copy, Snipping Tool, or any other 3rd Party Screen Copy Software, I can not paste my selection unless it is the very next step I do.

Example: I can't copy something from a word document, open up my web email, compose a new message, and then paste into them email. I have to open up the web email, compose the message first, then copy from a word document and immediately paste it into the web email.

If I don't paste immediately after I copy, it's like I never did the initial copy in the first place.

Comment: It seems like your Clipboard is emptying by itself. I May be mistaken but try clearing the virtual memory with Disk Clean-up

Comment: If that does not work open an Elevated cmd window (as administrator) and type "sfc /scannow"

Comment: When was the first time you noticed this issue? Does it happen if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: Process Monitor (Google for it) may help to see what is accessing the clipboard.

Comment: @and31415 I got a brand new laptop from work a couple of months ago and it has been happening the whole time. Clean boot didn't help.

Comment: And what about [Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7)?

Comment: This happens even in Safe Mode